# What's the best way to implement a Java-like ByteBuffer in Obj-C?

Tags: java, objective-c, porting

I'm trying to build a application for the iPhone, although I am completely new to Obj-C. For one problem I'd use a ByteBuffer in Java, but I don't see any appropriate class in Apple's documentation. So I probably have to implement it on my own.

My question is, how to do it best:

- Is there a similar class in Obj-C? (That would be the best solution ;))
- Should I do it by using Obj-C classes like NSData?
- Or should I stay with plain C code?

Comment: It really depends on what you're trying to do. You should edit your question to add a little more context.

Comment: My aim is to implement a fully functional Obj-C version of java.nio.ByteBuffer. Just wanted to know what I should use to get there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably want NSMutableData.

Comment: Ok... do you have any example how to read a e.g. a float from NSMutableData? Or any other data type?

Comment: AFAIK there are no such methods, but you can implement them yourself as a category of NSData, so they're usable with NSData and any of its subclasses.  Just use getBytes:length: to fetch sizeof(float) bytes and then cast the buffer.

Answer (score 6):

My recollection of `java.nio.ByteBuffer` (from working with Java many moons ago) is that `ByteBuffer` implements sequential reads/writes to an array of bytes. This is analogous to an `NSInputStream` backed by an `NSData` (for input):

```
NSInputStream *inputStream = [NSInputStream inputStreamwithData:myData]; //assuming myData is NSData*

float myFloat;

if([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) { // NO if you've already read to the end of myData
  NSInteger bytesRead = [inputStream read:&myFloat maxLength:sizeof(myFloat)];
  NSAssert(bytesRead == sizeof(myFloat);
}
```

You can do something similar with an `NSOutputStream` writing to an `NSData`.

Comment: This looks pretty promising. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm curious to see how your port turns out and would be very interested in using the result. Please ping me when it's ready.

Comment: I'm done with a working Obj-C version of ByteBuffer. You can have a look at it here:
http://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser/blob/objc/objc/src/ByteBuffer.h,
http://github.com/koraktor/steam-condenser/blob/objc/objc/src/ByteBuffer.m

Comment: The github.com links are broken, but I'm very excited to take a look when the code is back up.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I had to delete the branch again as it contained some things I didn't want to be online at the moment. But I forget to push the up to GitHub again.
They're online now.

Comment: Hey Koraktor i need your Obj-c version of Byte buffer.Would you please give me your updated github link or guide me what should i need to read for  implement Java ByteBuffer with Objective c or Swift.Thanks.

Comment: @Koraktor could you please share Obj-c version of Byte buffer? please

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar question. [ilya pointed my here with his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18658871/529543) .

> My aim is to implement a fully functional Obj-C version of
>   java.nio.ByteBuffer. Just wanted to know what I should use to get
>   there

That will be your custom class.

For my case I think `NSInputStream` and `NSOutputStream` should be used. For sure not `NSMutableData` as how is the accepted and mostly up voted answer.