# ios low level serialisation

Tags: android, ios, optimization, serialization

Here is a Java / Android function:

```
public static byte[] serialize(MyClass myObject) {

    int byteArraySizeNeeded = getByteArraySizeNeededForSerialize(myObject);

    byte[] result = new byte[byteArraySizeNeeded];
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(result);
    bb.putShort((short) (byteArraySizeNeeded-2));// 2 - not need to read at deserialisation!

    bb.putLong(myObject.getProperty1ValueWhichIsALong());// 8
    bb.putDouble(myObject.getProperty2ValueWhichIsADouble());// 8
    bb.putFloat(myObject.getProperty3ValueWhichIsAFloat);//4
    bb.put(CODE_MYCODE1); // code
    bb.putFloat(myObject.getProperty4ValueWhichIsAFloat);

// there are a lot of properties and the list is dynamic: some need to be saved some not: eg if property 10 exists than not needed to save property 11 and property 25 is saved only if not null and so on.

    int curPosition = bb.position();
    int offset = 2; // skip the first 2 bytes representing the size of byte buffer needed to allocate.
    int byteCount = curPosition - offset;

    myObject.crc.update(result, offset, byteCount);
    long crcValue = myObject.crc.getValue();

    bb.put(CODE_CRC); // code
    bb.putLong(crcValue);// only distinct data values

    return result;
}
```

I would like to do at iOS too. Or I miss or can't find a low level data structure / class what to use.

[NSData](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSMutableData](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html) claim to be an object which wraps a byte array, but they usefully function is only the [dataContentsOfFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSData/dataWithContentsOfFile%3a) and [writeToFile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile%3aatomically%3a).

[NSArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is like an ObjectOutputStream.

[Archives and Serializations Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingctypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001294-96941-BBCDIHEF)
Can't find any method which not required to put a key like encodeBytes:length:forKey:

I don't want to reinvent the wheel, nor use a lot of unnecessary data at saving.

Is any utility class which has a putLong() putFloat() putInt() and make a char or byte array properly?

Comment: Hmmm, do you try NSCache?

[NSCache example][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817476/how-to-store-data-in-nscache-in-ios

Comment: @daro2189 is a bit worse than NSMutableDictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found [the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/678069/whats-the-best-way-to-implement-a-java-like-bytebuffer-in-obj-c) and this answer is based on it. You can easily create a class that implements the same interface as ByteBuffer using [NSOutputStream](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSOutputStream_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001983-BAJJIEJB). Something like this:

```
- (NSOutputStream*)outputStream {
    if (_outputStream == nil) {
        _outputStream = [[NSOutputStream alloc] initToMemory];
        [_outputStream open];
    }
    return _outputStream;
}

- (void)putInt:(NSInteger)value {
    [self.outputStream write:(uint8_t*)&value maxLength:sizeof(NSInteger)];
}

- (NSData*)data {
    return [self.outputStream propertyForKey:NSStreamDataWrittenToMemoryStreamKey];
}
```

Comment: +1 thank you,  I will check at office the code and probably it will be accepted the answer too