# How would you match two class in objective-c

Tags: java, objective-c

So im trying to figure out how to match two classes in objective-c from my Java code.

The java code is as follows:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public interface IClient extends Serializable {
    String        getDeviceID();
    void          setDeviceID(String id);
    String        getNickname();
    void          setNickname(String name);
    boolean       matches(IClient client);
}
```

and the other class is as follows:

```
import xxx.xxx.xxx.interfaces.IClient;

public class Client implements IClient {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private   String deviceid;
    private   String nickname;

    public Client() {
        deviceid  = "";
        nickname  = "";
    }

@Override
public String getDeviceID() {
    return this.deviceid;
}

@Override
public void setDeviceID(String id) {
    this.deviceid = (id == null) ? "" : id.trim();
}

@Override
public String getNickname() {
    return this.nickname;
}

@Override
public void setNickname(String name) {
    this.nickname = (name == null) ? "" : name.trim();
}

@Override
public boolean matches(IClient client) {
    if (client != null) {
        if (client == this) {
            return true;
        }
        if (client.getDeviceID().equals(deviceid) &&     client.getNickname().equals(nickname)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

So I dont quite get how you would go about to convert the boolean, the code is on Objective-c atm is that IClient i a protocol and Client inherits it as follows:

```
Client.h

#import <Foundations/Foundation.h>
@protocol IClient <NSObject>
-(NSString*) DeviceID;
-(NSString*) Nickname;
-(BOOL) matches; // dont really know how to do that one
@end

IClient.h

#import <Foundations/Foundation.h>
#import "IClient.h"

@interface Client : NSObject <IClient>

//etc..

@end
```

Any help is welcome.

Comment: What do you mean by "match"? What is your ultimate goal with this project?

Comment: matching "classes": if([obj1 isKindOfClass:[obj2 class]]). Matching objects: if(self == obj)

Comment: Seems to me you'd do it the exact same way, using properties for your two string variables.  You, of course, need to properly declare/implement "matches", with an `id<IClient>` parameter.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels The "ultimate goal" is just to translate an java/android project into objective-c, so i'm just starting out with objective-c and I havn't done any C earlier so takes a bit of time to get used to all the new syntaxes etc.

Comment: @HotLicks: Are you going to post that as an answer?

Comment: I never give a direct answer to anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Hot Licks already said in a comment, the correct parameter type for the match method
is `id<IClient>`, which is *"any Objective-C object that conforms to the IClient protocol"*,
and you should use properties instead of instance variables.

Then you have:

**IClient.h:**

```
@protocol IClient <NSObject>
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *deviceID;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *nickName;
-(BOOL)matches:(id<IClient>)client;
@end
```

**Client.h:**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "IClient.h"

@interface Client : NSObject <IClient>
// ...
@end
```

and finally **Client.m:**

```
#import "Client.h"

@implementation Client
@synthesize deviceID = _deviceID;
@synthesize nickName = _nickName;

- (BOOL)matches:(id<IClient>)client
{
    if (client != nil) {
        if (client == self)
            return YES;
        if ([client.deviceID isEqualTo:self.deviceID] && [client.nickName isEqualTo:self.nickName])
            return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
@end
```

The `@synthesize` statements cause the compiler to create getter and setter methods,
backed up by instance variables `_deviceID`, `_nickName`.

Normally one can omit the `@synthesize` statements as well, but properties defined
in protocols are *not* synthesized automatically.

Comment: Thanks that did the job, I have been using "@property" and "@synthesize" in other non protocol classes, was adviced to not use it in protcols but I guess it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18658871/529543) is how is made a low level serialisation. The object level is with [NSArchiver](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/Documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArchiver_Class/Reference/Reference.html), [NSCoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSCoder_Class/Reference/NSCoder.html)